# Node in the groovy. Could not find matching constructor for: groovy.util.Node(groovy.util.NodeList, java.lang.String)

Tags: groovy, xmlslurper

```
def xmlRecords = new XmlParser().parseText(peopleString)

  //  println xmlRecords.person.subject_datas
    println "123"
    def datas = xmlRecords.person.subject_datas
    def newNode = new Node(datas, 'subject_data')
    def newSubNode = new Node(newNode, "subject_field_id", ["type", "integer"], "123max offer")
    def newSubNode1 = new Node(newNode, "value", "1000")
    def newNode2 = new Node(datas,"subject_data")
    def newSubNode2 = new Node(newNode, "subject_field_id", ["type", "integer"], "123application Status")
    def newSubNode21 = new Node(newNode, "value", "APPLIED")
```

Hi All,

I am face to a problem when I am trying to update a xml response.

I am using parseText to convert xmlstring to node. And then use the constructer to create a Node obj. new Node(NodeList, Object(name))

I got confused by the name which should use Object. When I put String here I got Could not find matching constructor for: groovy.util.Node(groovy.util.NodeList, java.lang.String). Do I need to convert String to Object? ?_?

Comment: First take a look at Node class and its available constructors. You have not added any inputs and what actually you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I check the Node class. All the way to setup a name for  a Node, the type of name is Object. Just wondering in this case how can we set up the name of a new Node? @SandeepPoonia.

Comment: Could you please provide the sample input and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Updated. Got the issue. The issue is not from name. It is from Node/NodeList. What I got from 'new XmlParser().parseText(peopleString)' is NodeList. What I should do is get(0). This is the high level Node in the NodeList. Put Node in the new Node() is working

Comment: peopleString is the very first input which is a xmlstring